# simple fetching api with hooks and printing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to import a card API using react hooks and print the cards to the browser but I can't figure out how?

[This is the structure of the api](https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=5)

Im trying to use the .map function to access the "image"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState ([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=5')
      const data = await response.json();
      setDeck(data);
      console.log(data)
    }, []);

  return (
      <ul>
        {deck.map(a => (<li> {a.cards.image}</li>))} // how to access api's "image" ??
      </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Do you want `{deck.cards.map(a => (<li> {a.image}</li>))}` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Vicente, have a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/random-cards-90kyz) to see an example of how you could implement it. And here is the `App` component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [deck, setDeck] = React.useState({ cards: [] });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=5"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setDeck(data);
      console.log(data);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {deck.cards.map((card, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <img src={card.image} alt={card.code} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

An important thing to take into account is that `React.useEffect` should run `synchronously`. Instead of passing an `async` function into it, define an `async` function inside the `useEffect` callback, and run it synchronously. Inside this new function you can `await` for promises to resolve, and you can set the state inside this function. Please read ["React's `useEffect`" docs for more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Another problem you had was that you were instantiating the `deck` state with an empty array (`[]`). But, the response is an object, so when you updated your `state` you got an error. I solve that by initializing the `deck` state with an object that defined a `cards` list, following the result of your endpoint.